# Observable abort or not?

Tags: angular, ionic2

If I have one http observable method and is called two times in one second, will the second call abort the first one automatically or do I have to use unsubscribe on the first http call to stop it?

This is to limit the http calls in a google map where I run a http call every time there is a zoom, in mobile can happen that the zoom is zoomed out more than once in a short period of time.

```
getClusters(params) {
    if(this.ajaxCall) {
      this.ajaxCall.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.ajaxCall = this.http
      .post(`${LOCAL_URL}/getClusters`, params)
      .subscribe((response: Response) => {
        response.json();
      });
      return this.ajaxCall;
  }
```

Comment: use `.switchMap()`

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout switchMap operator. It cancels preceding observable.

This could be helpful https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/search_with_switchmap.html